# How to extract a string after matching characters from a variable in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, sh

I have a file with following text as below

```
classA = Something
classB = AB1234567
classC = Something more
classD = Something Else
```

**Objective:**
Using a shell script, I want to read the text which says `AB1234567` from above complete text.

So to start, I can read the second line of the above text using following logic in my shell script:

```
secondLine=`sed -n '2p' my_file`;
echo $secondLine;
```

`secondLine` outputs `classB = AB1234567`. How do I extract `AB1234567` from `classB = AB1234567` in my shell script?

**Question:**
Considering the fact that `AB` is common in that particular part of the text all the files I deal with, how can I make `sed` to read all the numbers after `AB`?

Please note that `classB = AB1234567` could end with a space or a newline. *And I need to get this into a variable*

Comment: Not sure why my question was down-voted but anyways. Thanks a lot for the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
sed '2{ s/^classB = \(AB[^ ]*\) *$/\1/;q } ;d' your_fileName
```

- `2` is the line number.

  - `{` open a *sed* group command.

    - `s/` substitute below match

      - `^` is anchor for beginning of the line
      - `\(...\)` is known a capture group with `\1` as its back-reference
      - `[^ ]*` means any character but not a space
      - `\(AB[^ ]*\)` capture AB followed by anything until first space seen but not spaces (back-reference is `\1`)
      - `*` means zero-or-more spaces
      - `$` is anchor for end of the line
    - `/` with below

      - `\1` back-reference of above capture group
    - `/` end of substitution
    - `q` quit to avoid reading rest of the file unnecessarily
  - `}` close group command.
- `d` delete any other lines before seen line number 2.

get into variable:

```
your_variableName=$(sed '2{ s/^classB = \(AB[^ ]*\) *$/\1/;q } ;d' your_fileName)
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following, looks should be easy in `awk`. Considering you want to print 2nd line and print only digits in last field.

```
secondLine=$(awk 'FNR==2{sub(/[^0-9]*/,"",$NF);print $NF}' Input_file)
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please use the variable `secondLine` and put this into another variable called `searchedtext` or something?

Comment: @AdeleGoldberg, Done, could you please let me know if this helped you?

Comment: This works as well. Confused which answer to choose. Such intelligent minds out there! Thanks a lot

Comment: @AdeleGoldberg, your welcome, its up to you which answer you select we all are here to learn, cheers and happy learning and sharing :)

Answer (score 2):

You may try this `awk`:

```
awk -F ' *= *' '$1 ~ /B$/ { print $2 }' file
```

```
AB1234567
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please use the variable `secondLine` and put this into another variable called `searchedtext` or something?

Comment: you can do `secondLine=$(awk -F ' *= *' '$1 ~ /B$/ { print $2 }' file)` to put output in a variable

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you're looking for, but if you know there's only a single element in the file that starts with `AB`, this will get it into a variable:

```
$ cat sample.txt 
classA = Something
classB = AB1234567
classC = Something more
classD = Something Else
  
$ x=$(perl -ne 'print if s/^.*\s+(AB\S+)\s*$/$1/' sample.txt)
 
$ echo "the variable is: $x"
the variable is: AB1234567
```

Explanation of the regex:

- `^` beginning of line
- `.*` anything
- `\s+` any number of spaces
- `(AB\S+)` anything that starts with `AB` followed by non-spaces
- `\s*$` Zero or more spaces followed by the end of the line.